# Having a Fullscreen preview image onHover property in Mapbox GL to cover entire map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

Currently I have a ReactMapboxGL component with markers. These markers have a onMouseEnter function that brings up a fullscreen popup to my screen, but that not what I want. Currently I'm trying to replicate this design with my Markers (http://www.francoisrisoud.com/projects), where if you hover over a dot it gives a fullscreen preview image and only if that is clicked on, it'll go to that particular page.

Currently this is my code:

```
export default function Map({ posts }) {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 36.592206968562685,
    longitude: 3.332469343750031,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 1.3,
    scrollZoom: "false",
    
  });

  const [selectedProperty, setSelectedProperty] = useState(null);
  const [isPopupShown, setIsPopupShown] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
    <div className="root">
    {!isPopupShown && (
      <div className="map">
      <ReactMapGL
      scrollZoom="false"
        {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken="//myAPIkey"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/jay5053/cks5xkaa892cp17o5hyxcuu0z"
        onViewportChange={(viewport) => {
          setViewport(viewport);
        }}
      >
        {posts &&
          posts.map((maps) => (
            <Marker
              key={maps.id}
              latitude={maps.Latitude}
              longitude={maps.Longitude}
            >
              <button
                    className="marker-btn"
                    onMouseEnter={() => {
                      setSelectedProperty(maps);
                      setViewport({
                        latitude: 36.592206968562685,
                        longitude: 3.332469343750031,
                        width: "0vw",
                        height: "0vh",
                        zoom: 1.3
                      });
                      setIsPopupShown(true);
                    }}
                  >
                <img src="placeholder.svg" />
              </button>
            </Marker>
          ))}
          </ReactMapGL>
        </div>
      )}

      {selectedProperty && isPopupShown && (
        <div className="full-popup">
          // todo: Have the fullscreen as a hover to close it?
        </div>
      )}
    </div>

      </>
      
  );
}
```

I've added a sandbox for reference if anyone wants to test it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-myu0i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [HTMLOverlay](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/html-overlay)

```js
          <HTMLOverlay
            redraw={(props) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                    width: isPopupShown ? props.width : 0,
                    height: isPopupShown ? props.height : 0,
                    transition: "all .2s ease-in-out",
                    transform: "scale(1.1)",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  <h1>Text</h1>
                </div>
              );
            }}
          />
```

Forked your sandbox to create a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-srfvp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: How do I have an onclick for each marker that will take me to different pages?

Comment: You should attach a click handler to the markers.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again, I'm trying to add a different image for each marker, but all of them keep showing 1 image. Can you help me out, I've added a sandbox for the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-p8934?file=/src/App.js